# Spring Boot relation returns null

Tags: java, spring-boot, relation

I have a problem with Spring Boot relation. The problem occurs when method create returns method read (NullPointerException) because it can't access a method from object that is in one to one relation with project class (project.getColors().getValue()).

```
package Main.Controller;

import Main.Model.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/project")
public class ProjectController {

@Autowired
private ProjectRepository projectRepository;

@RequestMapping(path = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Object create(@RequestBody CreateProjectObject object) {

    Project project=new Project();
    project.setName(object.getName());
    project.setColor(object.getValue());
    projectRepository.save(project);
    return this.read();
}

@RequestMapping(path = "/read", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Map<String, Object>> read() {
    List<Map<String, Object>> readProject = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Project project: projectRepository.findAll()
    ) {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("value", project.getId());
        map.put("color", project.getColors().getValue());//           <--------
        map.put("label", project.getName());
        readProject.add(map);
    }
    return readProject;
}
```

But the thing is, method read reads all the other projects that were created before without a problem. And if I call that method few seconds later it reads the same projects that it couldn't read few moments earlier.
Here is the Project model:

```
package Main.Model;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Column
@CreationTimestamp
private LocalDateTime created_at;

@Column
@UpdateTimestamp
private LocalDateTime updated_at;

private String name;

private Integer color;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "color", insertable =  false, updatable = false)
private Color colors;

public Color getColors() {
    return colors;
}

public void setColors(Color colors) {
    this.colors = colors;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Integer getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setColor(Integer color) {
    this.color = color;
}

}
```

EDIT: Here is the Color class

```
package Main.Model;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "colors")
public class Color {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Column
@CreationTimestamp
private LocalDateTime created_at;

@Column
@UpdateTimestamp
private LocalDateTime updated_at;

private String value;

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String name) {
    this.value = value;
}


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add CascadeType.ALL in the @OneToOne relationship. Also, [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/) is an easy tutorial to understand JPA relationships.

Comment: I added @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) and I still get the same null pointer exception. Thank you for the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

User `@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)` as by default it will load `LAZY`.

there is one more point if your joining color from Color class then not required `private Integer color;` or if its for something else then might conflict with `@JoinColumn`

```
@OneToOne((cascade = CascadeType.ALL), fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "colors", insertable =  false, updatable = false)
private Color colors;
```

and your project create method should also set colors:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Object create(@RequestBody CreateProjectObject object) {

        Project project=new Project();
        project.setName(object.getName());
        project.setColor(object.getValue());
        Color color = new Color();
        color.setId(object.getValue());
        project.setColors(color);
        projectRepository.save(project);
        return this.read();
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error. Integer color has nothing to do with class Color. Thank you for your help

Comment: try to debug and check projectRepository.findAll() was loading Color object??Can you also show your color entity

Comment: Can you change this to name = "colors"  not color

Comment: and after this please let me know by looking table you have inserted data..and what repository.all returns??

Comment: if still not work then please post your sample project to github, I will take a look or also add Color entity and CreateProjectObject pojo..

Comment: one more thing remove @ResponseBody from controller methods as RestController add controller and requestBody so not required to add at method level.

Comment: When I run in debug mode projectRepository.findAll() returns everything except colors object (it is null). Projects are created in the database. I have removed @ResponseBody. I will now add Colors class so you can see what's in it.

Comment: yeah thats issue, show me all classes, which I requested so i can look at my end..one more thing remove insertable/updatable and add  CascadeType.ALL  too

Comment: its not inserting colors in projects table so cascading is required and to load EAGER is required by default..

Comment: please also add CreateProjectObject as I will create at my end exact and check

Comment: i just noticed at project creation time you are not setting colors object..

Comment: I am little confuse by seeing your color class as do not have bidirectional and not even saving color then how you are loading one to one, you can load one to one then you have project id at color side